# Cannot convert all of the TXT to CSV files in the folder

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code that is supposed to iterate through all of the files in the folder, however it fails to iterate through all the files. I have added there parameter to ignore errors in reading but it still fails. 
I tried various reading and writing modes - "rb", "wb", "w+"with no avail.
Any ideas?

```
import os
import csv
import glob

cwd = os.getcwd()

directory = cwd

output = cwd

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "r", errors = 'ignore') as input_file:
        in_txt = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='|')
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

        with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'w+') as output_file:
            out_csv = csv.writer(output_file)
            out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: Fails in which way?

Comment: are you sure you should use `in_txt` in `writerows` ? `writerows` may expect list of rows but `in_txt` is csv reader, not list of rows.

Comment: There is no error message. The script just stops and does not go through all files in the folder.